# Selenium как убрать этот текст в консоли?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Когда запускаю код, то при запуске браузера появляется много текста. Как это убрать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все настройки которые я наскрёб, но не уверен как они работают

````
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

Или так еще:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.EnableVerboseLogging = false;
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;

options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--disable-crash-reporter");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces");
options.AddArgument("--disable-logging");
options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
options.AddArgument("--output=/dev/null");
Browser = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

Comment: всё ещё появляется

Comment: какой браузер используете?

Comment: основной - opera, но что-бы селениум работал скачал chrome

Comment: второй вариант тоже не работает